# Bake Video to Sound

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio

I have a video clip. I want it to match with the speed of the music. Whenever there is a beat in the music the speed of the video should increase and visa versa. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a video clip as a strip in the VSE. Then you can add a speed effect strip to it. The speed effect strip can be altered by animating the multiply factor of the speed value. Then you could import a sound and use the Bake Sound to Fcurve function. Use this curve to drive the multiply speed.